# SQL error 1064 syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have an error in sql:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'go' at line 28

Does somebody know what is wrong with syntax here?

```
INDEX avangard_log_ticket_ndx USING btree(ticket),
INDEX avangard_log_ok_code_ndx USING btree(ok_code)
) ENGINE = INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cigo;
```

Comment: `COLLATE utf8_general_cigo` what is that? copy-paste error? Since in your error it says `near 'go'` I suppose you are trying some t-sql in mysql? `GO` does not exist in `MySQL` at all.

Comment: Extra `)` and misspelled `COLLATE`

Answer (score 0):

utf8_general_cigo
 should be `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Please expand on your answer, this is too little.